# How to detect sentences in a <p> tag that contain a <span> tag between periods

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect/grab sentences in a < p > tag that contain a < span > tag. I want to get the entire sentence between a set of periods. This has to be done for the whole webpage.

For example the following paragraph contains the span sentence that I want to extract:

```
<p>The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior. Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell.</p>
```

I would only like to extract the sentence: "Because the phosphate groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid" because it contains the < span > tag

Can I do this to whole webpage? Using regex or js?

I've tried different regex combinations online but none of them work.

Comment: have you tried indexOf('<span>')> - 1 approach?

Comment: @EugeneSunic - By the looks of it OP hasn't tried anything.

Comment: @eternalHour for a very simple problem I would totally agree, but I had to research *a lot* to answer this, I won't vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

```
   for(const span of document.querySelectorAll("p span")) {
      const prevText = span.previousSibling.data;
      const afterText = span.nextSibling.data;
      const prev = prevText.slice( prevText.lastIndexOf(".") );
      comst after = afterText.slice(0, afterText.indexOf("."));
       // do whatever you wanna do here
   }
```

Using the DOM's methods you can go over all `<span>`s in `<p>`s, and access the text before and after it with `previousSibling` and `nextSibling` respectively. To get the "sentence" around it, use the . to seperate the sentences.

This is by far not finished, there might be cases were the previous or the following node aren't text nodes, or were there is no dot in those textnodes. You have to handle those cases appropriately.

See:

[`Node` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#Properties)

[`Text` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)

[`.querySelectorAll` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: This code is good, but it doesn't get the text in the span tags and I don't know how to get the entire sentence? It seems to be broken, ie. " , the nervous tissue contained within the cranium, and the
 , the extension of nervous tissue within the vertebral column"

Comment: Well, `span.textContent` if you need that. Not sure what you mean, it's your turn now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JavaScript. Let's store the sentences in an array.

Sentences:

```
<p>The sun is <span>shining</span> today</p>
<p>Let's refactorate it</p>
<p>Nice. It's a <span>special day</span> of celebration</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var sentences = [];

document.querySelectorAll('p span').forEach(function(span) {
    var sentencesText = span.parentNode.innerText.split('.');
    span.parentNode.innerHTML.split('.').forEach(function(sent, i) {
        if (sent.indexOf("<span>") != -1) {
            sentences.push(sentencesText[i]);
        }
    })
});
```

Result of `sentences` array:

```
"The sun is shining today"
"It's a special day of celebration"
```

Comment: This won't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes. I misinterpreted it. I will edit.

Comment: Edited. A little verbose, but it seems to work well. I prefer your answer, though

Comment: Your code splits every single sentence. Even those without the span tag

Comment: It only adds to array what is described in the question: "the entire sentence between a set of periods". Check the example that the OP wrote and test the code. But the span have to close and open in the same sentence (between 2 periods), though.

Answer (score 0):

separate the sentences using the `split` method, and then search which one has `span`

```js
const p=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
p.split(".").forEach(e=>{
  if(e.indexOf('span')>0){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

```html
<p>The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior. Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick & Dirty solution with Regular Expressions.

*Please note that this code will need some extra work to take into account more characters in the text.* This is just a simple example that uses the basic text you added in your question, and to demonstrate it is possible to solve it using regular expressions.

```js
const getSentences = () => {
  let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  let sentences = [];
  paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
    paragraph = paragraph.innerHTML;
    sentences.push(paragraph.match(/(<p>)?\.?\s?[\w\d\s]+<span>(\w)+<\/span>\s?[\w\d\s,]{1,}\.\s?/ig));
  });
  return sentences;
};

getSentences().forEach((sentence) => {
  console.log(sentence);
});
```

```css
p > span {
  background: #d2d2d2;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1 <span> tag per <p> -->
<p>The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior. 1 Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell.</p> 
<!-- End 1 <span> tag per <p> -->

<!-- Multiple <span> tags per <p> -->
<p>The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior. 2 Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell. The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior. 3 Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. The phospholipid heads face outward, one layer exposed to the interior of the cell and one layer exposed to the exterior.</p>
<!-- End Multiple <span> tags per <p> -->

<!-- 1 <span> tag per <p> at the beggining -->
<p>4 Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid. Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell.</p> 
<!-- End 1 <span> tag per <p> at the beggining -->

<!-- 1 <span> tag per <p> at the end -->
<p>Intracellular fluid (ICF) is the fluid interior of the cell. 5 Because the <span>phosphate</span> groups are polar and hydrophilic, they are attracted to water in the intracellular fluid.</p> 
<!-- End 1 <span> tag per <p> at the end -->
```